# How to join two tables multiple column in JPQL?

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, jpql

```
SELECT * FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD1 AND A.FIELD2 = B.FIELD2
```

How to write this query in JPQL?

Comment: What are the entity classes for A and B? Do you have any JPA relationships between the two entities defined, so that JPQL can figure out how to join by itself?

Answer (score 1):

It's in principle not different from SQL. Check [Apache OpenJPA tutorial](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_Joins) or [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from) for example.